# Is it possible for a gigabit switch to be PoE-powered?

Tags: networking, switch, power-over-ethernet

I'm in need of a gigabit switch that can be powered via PoE, rather than AC power. There isn't any AC power in the area where it needs to be installed. Is this possible?

Comment: You're going to have to run either AC or DC power to the area. How many ports are we talking?

Comment: You mean the switch, itself, needs power, and not just the ports coming from the switch?

Comment: How is this not a shopping question?

Comment: Normally, this would be deemed a shopping question. However, I think that this is a special application and there are *very* few products that can do this. I thought I'd share my experience since it could be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: this is not a shopping question. if someone asked "is there a product that allows users to backup their files automatically over the internet?" i bet you would close that. and i MIGHT agree with that. however, if someone asked "is there a product that centrally stores all microsoft office documents in a database like structure for easy searching?", would that be a shopping question? obvious answers would be autonomy imanage or worldox, but that is hardly a shopping question. the asked has no idea there is even such a product!

Comment: @longneck: All of the scenarios you describe are 'shopping' by our definition.

Comment: ** "is there a product that centrally stores all microsoft office documents in a database like structure for easy searching?", would that be a shopping question? ** Well, um, yes. What you're apparently saying is that a shopping question isn't a shopping question if what you're shopping for is difficult to find, and with respect, that's nonsense.

Answer (score 31):

The [HP ProCurve 1810-8G Switch](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10195732/mfg_partno/J9449A) (J9449A) is an 8-port Gigabit switch that can be powered by an upstream PoE switch. I use it in environments where I can't accommodate a power brick or need to control power from a central location (e.g. a UPS in a central server room). They're also nice when you need to use small switches because of a lack of ethernet drops in a facility.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I have never seen a switch that ran off PoE.  Those might be useful to put on our mobile lab carts.

Comment: Ditto @Zoredache - this is the kind of thing I'd have almost ruled out directly. Interesting to know

Comment: Does it forward the PoE current? This one is not Gbit but is able to do that, but I'm interested in Gbit, too. http://www.veracityglobal.com/products/ethernet-and-poe-devices/outreach-quad-lite.aspx

Comment: There's nothing on the market that forwards the PoE current.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you will find such a product. Instead, I would look for a generic PoE injector/extractor.

I think this is one of those products, but I can't get the website to load.

http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=332

Comment: I think OP wants to power the switch itself via POE.  A midspan or injector still needs AC running to it.

Comment: That is not what I was suggesting. They make devices that sit at the end of the span and split Ethernet from the PoE.

Comment: Ah, I see, then +1.

Comment: We use these for some impromptu wireless "access points" in an area that are really just specially configured consumer wifi routers, set up in area that needed simple wifi coverage very cheaply. Hopefully the so-called APs will start breaking soon so I can replace them with real equipment.

Comment: then this product is perfect. that's exactly what it's designed for: powering consumer-grade networking devices that need 12 or 5 volts.